# Is it possible to create and execute a deep learning model and doing its prediction in c++?

Tags: deep-learning, contiki

Let's suppose that  my chip doesn't support any API like keras, tensorflow or sklearn; however I need to implement a  deep learning model in python.

Is it possible to make my training and testing model in python, then,  I want  to call the best model results for prediction with C++? 
Where I mus save the resulted best model in order to be called in the next steps? Must I  save it in the chip? Did I need to install tensorflow and keras in my chip in this case?

Comment: @Tim where could I ask such question please ?

Answer (score 2):

**TERMINOLOGY**

You seem to be confused about terminology.  Here's a somewhat simplified overview.

Your **chip** is the hardware (CPU or GPU), and will include circuitry to support its instruction set (move data to/from local memory, perform math and logic operations, etc.).  A CPU/GPU **chip** that cannot support your ML software is hard to visualize, and would not support Python or C++, either.  The **chip** comes on a **board**, which includes a lot of peripheral connections, secondary memory, etc.

Then your **operating system** (basic software) is installed on the hardware.  This **OS** manages resources: jobs, processes, memory allocation, etc.  If there's a failure in support, it would be here, not in the **chip**.  Finally, you install your desired **applications** (software tools, programs, etc.) as additions to the OS.

C++ and Python are two high-level languages, popular **applications**.  These languages support Tensorflow and Keras (machine learning frameworks) and SciKit (scientific / statistical package; *sklearn* is the package name you import).

---

**DIRECT ANSWER**

Yes, you can write your NN in Python.  Yes, you can call it from C++.  Python depends on C/C++ libraries; there is a viable interface between the two.

There is no particular method you *must* use to save your model and call it later: if you're writing your own model in Python, you get to decide the storage format and location.  All you need is to have your Python and C++ programs "agree" on the format.  Since you're writing them both, then you can choose whatever works for you.

**RECOMMENDATION**

Don't write these yourself, unless you *really* want the exercise.  Instead, install a framework (TensorFlow, Caffe, Neon, Torch, MXNet, Keras, ...).  Then, simply follow the given tutorials to learn how to build, save, and restore your model.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but my problem is that my chip contains ARC processor, and my operating system is contiki.  so I don't know which library to use. I feel that I am blocked

Comment: Please (1) edit these concerns into your question; (2) try posting the question in a contiki support forum.  I added the contiki tag for you.